# Loop through AMP web stories

Tags: amp-html, amp-story, amp-stories

Is there any way to loop through multiple [amp web stories](https://amp.dev/about/stories/) (or visual stories), so that a new story loads when a user scrolls to the end?

This is to reproduce app-like navigation (like facebook or youtube stories) when users scrolls through multiple stories without getting back to main page.

Something like [amp-next-page](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-next-page/) component, which does not seem to work inside amp-story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to loop through multiple stories by using the [Web Story Player](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/integrate/embed-stories/?format=stories).

If you're using it in AMP valid page, you can embed as many stories as you would like inside the [`<amp-story-player>` component](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-story-player/?format=stories#specify-embedded-stories). The player will show the next story to the viewer after finishing each one.

If you're embedding stories into a non-AMP page, you can [programmatically fetch more stories](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-story-player.md#programmatically-fetching-more-stories) as the user progresses, or [circularly wrap](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-story-player.md#circular-wrapping) a fixed number of stories to repeat in a loop.